# Latitude/longitude waypoint distance calculations, crosstrack, VMG, ETA, etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, geospatial

I'm in the process of a complete re-write of a stagnant and ill-conceived project. I would like some feedback on the following Python 2.7-3.4 code, before I go any deeper into it.

I would hope it is self-explanatory, but that is always the illusion when you stare at something long enough. The other dilemma is glossing over errors and squirrelly logic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""" waypoint.py
    A collection of waypoint and distance functions for the NxGPS Project:
    Getting the most out of a $30 gps, for Navigatrix (http://navigatrix.net)
    NxGPS project repository is (https://github.com/wadda/NxGPS)
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from pyproj import Geod  # sudo pip3 install pyproj
from cmath import asin, sin
import math
# from math import radians, degrees
# import gps3

conversion = {'nautical': 1852.0, 'imperial': 1609.344, 'metric': 1000.0, 'meters': 1.0}


class Odometer(object):
    """Odometer is a wrapper around pyproj.Geod distance calculations"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.bearing_to = None
        self.bearing_fro = None
        self.distance = {}

    def do_to_fro_distance(self, lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, units='meters'):
        """lat lon from point A and point B, returns True North
        bearings 'to', A-B(1-2), and 'fro', B-A (2-1) and distance in always
        fashionable meters with optional nautical, imperial, or (kilo)metric"""
        bearing_to = bearing_fro = self.distance['meters'] = None
        try:
            geoid = Geod(ellps='WGS84')
            bearing_to, bearing_fro, self.distance['meters'] = geoid.inv(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)

        except Exception as error:
            print("Can't calculate to/fro because:", error)

        finally:
            if units not in 'meters':
                self.distance[units] = self.distance['meters'] / conversion[units]

            self.bearing_to = bearing_to % 360
            self.bearing_fro = bearing_fro % 360

        return self.bearing_to, self.bearing_fro, self.distance


odometer = Odometer()


class Crosstrack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.startpoint_lat = None
        self.startpoint_lon = None
        self.a2b_radians = None
        self.trip_distance = {}  # similar to 'odometer.distance', except A to C distance from last reset.
        self.distance = {}

    def do_crosstrack(self, current_lat, current_lon, start_lat=None, start_lon=None,
                      end_lat=None, end_lon=None, units='meters'):
        """
        return crosstrack distance from current position, and last set track or
        return crosstrack distance from current position, start, and end positions

        Formula from:
        http: // williams.best.vwh.net / avform.htm  # XTE

        """
        default_lat = -15.560615  # Apataki Carenage
        default_lon = -146.241122  # Apataki Carenage
        default_a2b_radians = 4.2538533202126025  # bearing in radians Apataki to Kaputar
        earth_radius = 6371009.0  # meters...It's a mean radius, but nice enough.
        crosstrack_distance = {}

        try:
            if all([start_lon, start_lon, end_lat, end_lon]):  # both start and end shall start and end together.
                # A to B
                a2b_bearing, _, _ = odometer.do_to_fro_distance(start_lat, start_lon, end_lat, end_lon)
                self.a2b_radians = math.radians(a2b_bearing)
                self.startpoint_lat = start_lat
                self.startpoint_lon = start_lon
                # A to C
            if not any([start_lat, start_lon, end_lat, end_lon]):
                if not self.startpoint_lat:  # one is enough, or one is not enough, depending on perspective
                    self.startpoint_lat = default_lat  # resort to defaults
                    self.startpoint_lon = default_lon
                    self.a2b_radians = default_a2b_radians
                start_lat = self.startpoint_lat
                start_lon = self.startpoint_lon

            bearing_to, _, distance = odometer.do_to_fro_distance(start_lat, start_lon, current_lat, current_lon)
            a2c_radians = math.radians(bearing_to)

            self.trip_distance = distance  # Distance A to C in meters

            # Crosstrack calculations in radians, output as a complex numbers {'meters': (281.8893996162284+0j)
            crosstrack_distance['meters'] = (asin(sin(distance['meters']) * sin(a2c_radians - self.a2b_radians))
                                             * earth_radius)
        except Exception as error:
            print('Can\'t calculate crosstrack because: ', error)

        finally:
            if units not in 'meters':
                crosstrack_distance[units] = crosstrack_distance['meters'] / conversion[units]
                self.trip_distance[units] = self.trip_distance['meters'] / conversion[units]

            self.distance = crosstrack_distance.copy()

            # Printing for testing
            print('Positive should mean right of course, negative means left with the other choice.')
            for k, v in crosstrack_distance.items():
                print(k, ":", v.real)  # extract 'real' number

            print("Scabed on xtrk trip distance:", self.trip_distance)

            print('Real and imaginary in complex numbers:\n')

        return self.distance


crosstrack = Crosstrack()


# WIP
class BestScenario(object):
    """ Hypothetical 'if' calculations for speculation, fairy tales, and general BS
    deceptively based on a few 'real world' inputs.  Variations on a theme requiring
    current position
    current time
    current speed
    current course
    waypoint, distance and bearing
    """
    pass

    def closest_approach(self):
        """ Present course will pass X distance from waypoint,
        or course required to maintain minimum distance  (inverse crosstrack)
        current position
        waypoint
        """
        pass

    def eta(self):
        """ ETA given present course and speed
        waypoint distance and bearing
        current speed
        current course
        current time
        """
        pass

    def shortest(self):
        """ Shortest distance to waypoint given present course
        waypoint distance and bearing
        current course
        """
        pass

    def vmg(self):
        """ Velocity Made Good given present course and speed
        waypoint bearing
        current course
        current speed
        """
        pass

    def whentack(self):
        """ When to tack given present course, speed, and pre-determined angle
        waypoint bearing
        current course
        course delta required
        current speed
        """
        pass
```

Comment: It's easier to not have to think up test cases. On track `crosstrack.do_crosstrack(41.257307,-100.73410,41.29100,-100.73410,41.21998,-100.73410, units='nautical')` Less so; `crosstrack.do_crosstrack(41.257307,-100.73415)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not really clear why `Odometer` is a class. You only ever create one instance of it, and don't actually need any of the instance attributes. The only thing you *could* sensibly store as a class/instance attribute, the `Geod` instance, you actually recreate on every call.

Also, the error handling seems a bit odd - why `return` anything if you haven't actually been able to calculate a result? When you get to the `finally` block, you end up trying to do e.g. `self.bearing_to = None % 360`, which will just cause another error. You could either `return None`, as I do below, or pass the error (or your own error) up to the calling function to deal with.

It would be good to be more specific than `Exception`, too (I don't know what errors `inv` could throw, but you should find out and check *specifically* for them - see e.g. [*"the evils of `except`"*](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/)).

I would write this as a simple function:

```
CONVERSION = {  # note UPPERCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES for constants
    'imperial': 1609.344, 
    'metric': 1000.0,
    'nautical': 1852.0,
}  # no need for 'meters'

GEOID = Geod(ellps='WGS84')

def odometer(start, end, units='meters'):
    """Calculate bearings and distance between start and end.

    Arguments:
      start (tuple of float): latitude and longitude of starting position
      end (tuple of float): latitude and longitude of ending position
      units (str): the units to output distance (must be one of 'meters',
        'nautical' (miles), 'imperial' (miles) or 'metric' (km)). Defaults
        to 'meters'.

    Returns:
      float: True North bearing start -> end
      float: True North bearing end -> start
      float: distance start <-> end

    Raises:
      KeyError: if units isn't  'meters' or in CONVERSION

    """
    try:
        bearing_to, bearing_fro, distance = geoid.inv(*start+end)
    except Exception as error:  # try to be more specific here!
        print("Can't calculate to/fro because:", error)
        return None  # don't return anything if calculation fails
    # no 'finally' - if the calculation fails, we're done here! At most, use 'else'
    if units != 'meters':
        distance /= CONVERSION[units]  # in-place operators to simplify code
    bearing_to %= 360
    bearing_fro %= 360
    return bearing_to, bearing_fro, distance
```

I have simplified the arguments by taking two two-tuples `(lat, long)`, then unpacking them to `goeid.inv` (see [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for Python parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761) if this syntax is unfamiliar). Alternatively, you could use a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) (e.g. `Coord = namedtuple("Coord", "lat lon")`); this would allow you to access `.lat` and `.lon` attributes while still allowing tuple unpacking.

I have also provided a more informative docstring (this is the [Google style](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html), which I like, but others are available). Using formatted docstrings like this you can then automatically generate API documentation using tools like [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/).

---

The same is true for `Crosstrack`. Additionally, even if you were going to keep it in a class, it redefines constants each time `do_crosstrack` is called; these should be *class attributes* instead:

```
class Crosstrack(object):

    DEFAULT_LAT = -15.560615  # Apataki Carenage
    DEFAULT_LON = -146.241122  # Apataki Carenage
    DEFAULT_A2B_RADIANS = 4.2538533202126025  # bearing in radians Apataki to Kaputar
    EARTH_RADIUS = 6371009.0  # meters...It's a mean radius, but nice enough.

    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

But, again, this would be much simpler as a standalone function.

---

You also have a subtle bug; note that e.g.:

```
all([start_lon, start_lon, end_lat, end_lon]):
```

will be `False` not just if any are `None`, but if any are *zero* (an edge case, perhaps, but one you should consider). Per [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you should test for `None` by identity, using `is`:

```
all(coord is not None for coord in [start_lon, ...]):
```

---

For "work in progress" methods/functions, I would generally `raise NotImplementedError` rather than `pass`, so it reminds me I still need to write it if I accidentally call it before implementation.

Comment: I really like the idea of putting *lat/lon* into tuples of floats. It's a neater, tidier package. In spite of tuples made sporadic bug tracing difficult as **pyproj** requires lon-lat positional args and years of rote memory has me trained the other way.  Buried in a tuple it was *harder* to find.  I learned.  Now, there is no class.  One concession to a `global` variable so it could latch the start/end points and subsequent function calls only require a current position.  I like the documentation style and the `return None`  And finally, I understand `finally`.  I am indebted. Thx